# El pronombre de objeto indirecto en la oración “yo busco un trabajo para mí” ¿es obligatorio u opcional?

Tags: pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

La oración

> Yo busco un trabajo para mí

¿ha de seguir las mismas reglas que

> Yo me busco un trabajo a mí

o se puede usar sin pronombre átono? Y si la respuesta es sí ¿qué diferencia hay al cambiar **a** por **para**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta es una buena pregunta.

La cuestión es que la parte de la oración introducida por ***para***, no siempre es un complemento indirecto: en ocasiones es un **complemento circunstancial**.

En [este enlace](http://delenguayliteratura.com/sintagma_preposicional_con_para_complemento_indirecto_CI_o_complemento_circunstancial_destinatario.html) lo explican bien (para una fuente más oficial, tendrás que consultar una edición física de la Gramática de la RAE). No te copio el texto entero por no sobrecargar la respuesta:

> Son numerosos los gramáticos que, en la actualidad, consideran erróneo identificar un SPrep con “**para**” como CI. Nos encontramos en estos casos con un CC de Destinatario.

Centrándonos en tu ejemplo:

> Yo busco un trabajo **para mí** *[CI?]*.

Podría pensarse que es una oración con CI, pero ¿lo es? Vamos a añadir el pronombre personal del CI para asegurarnos:

> Yo **me** *[CI]* busco un trabajo **para mí** *[CI?]*.

Y ahora, probemos a cambiar el pronombre:

> Yo ***le*** *[CI]* busco un trabajo **para mí** *[CI???]*.

¡Sigue teniendo sentido! ¿Por qué? Porque, en realidad, "para mí" no es el CI:

> Yo ***le*** *[CI]* busco ***a tu padre*** *[CI]* un trabajo **para mí** *[<strike>CI</strike>CCDest]*.
>   Yo ***me*** *[CI]* busco ***a mí mismo*** *[CI]* un trabajo **para mí** *[<strike>CI</strike>CCDest]*.

Con lo visto en preguntas anteriores, ya sabemos que la obligatoriedad de mantener el pronombre aplica para el CI; pero en este caso no estamos hablando de un CI, sino de un CC, y por tanto no aplica la norma.
Entonces, si queremos hacer explícito el CI, debemos mantener el pronombre:

> Yo le busco a Juan un trabajo para su hermano. / Yo le busco un trabajo para su hermano.

Pero si no queremos incluir el CI, entonces no es necesario el pronombre:

> Yo busco un trabajo para su hermano.

Answer (score 3):

Hay una regla de sintaxis que dice que cuando se usa un pronombre de objeto con la preposición *a*, el pronombre átono correspondiente también debe estar presente. Esta regla ya la conoces.

Cuando la preposición que precede al objeto indirecto es *para*, no hay ninguna regla que obligue a incluir también el pronombre átono. *Yo busco un trabajo para mí* es correcto.

Otros ejemplos (todos correctos):

> *Le compré un libro.*
>   *Le compré un libro a ella.*
>   *Compré un libro para ella.*

Ten en cuenta que no se puede hacer esta misma sustitución con todos los verbos. Por ejemplo, el verbo *dar* es normalmente ditransitivo, es decir, requiere objeto directo e indirecto, y no se puede reemplazar el objeto indirecto (con *a*) por un complemento (con *para*): *Te di un regalo* está bien, pero *Di un regalo para ti* está mal.

Como asunto aparte: *Yo me busco un trabajo a mí* no es gramatical, porque aquí el objeto indirecto es reflexivo, así que si añades algo más también debe ser reflexivo: *Yo me busco un trabajo a mí mismo* (pero eso suena muy forzado). Este problema no existe si usas la preposición *para*. Puedes decir *Yo busco un trabajo para mí* y también *Yo busco un trabajo para mí mismo*. En el segundo caso el *mismo* es simplemente enfático, pero opcional.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas el pronombre. No puedes decir

> Yo busco un trabajo a mí

Ya que es casi como hablar en tercera persona de ti mismo. Puedes, por el contrario, decir

> Yo me busco un trabajo

ya que el "a mi" resulta un poco redundante al tener el pronombre "me" que ya indica sobre quién va a recaer la acción. En cualquier caso el "a mi" puede quedarse (o no)

> Ella me dijo a mi [tal o cual cosa]
>
> Ella le dijo a él [tal o cual cosa]

Aparte, por la naturaleza de la propia frase puedes decir simplemente

> (Yo) Busco trabajo

Ya que normalmente cuando buscamos un nuevo empleo suele ser para nosotros mismos y no para terceras personas.

> Busco una novia
>
> (Yo) (Me) Busco una novia (a mi)
>
> Busco una novia para mi amigo Alex

El uso de las preposiciones `a` o `para` ya puede depender de si estás usando el pronombre o no.

> Le busco una novia **a** mi amigo Alex
>
> Busco una novia **para** mi amigo Alex

---

Update:

La gramática tradicional identifica como complementos tanto `a mi novia` como `para mi novia`, porque ambos hacen referencia a la misma realidad. Pero estos dos complementos son distintos por mantener una distinta relación con el núcleo oracional, lo que prueba el hecho de que el complemento con `a` se puede reduplicar con el pronombre clítico le

> Le compré flores a mi novia.

mientras que en el complemento con `para` no se puede reduplicar con le.

> Le compré flores para mi novia

<sub>Fuente: [hispanoteca](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Complemento%20indirecto%20con%20a%20-%20para.htm)</sub>

Comment: Entoces, si entiendo bien: cuando usamos "**para**" en vez de "**a**" ¿podemos quitar el pronombre átono de objeto indirecto?

Comment: @walen, tienes razón, pero creo que hay dos preguntas en una (1- es correcta la frase sin el pronombre; 2- qué ocurre al cambiar _a_ por _apara_). Actualizaré la respuesta cuando tenga un poco de tiempo (No dudéis en publicar otras respuestas mientras tanto. Recordad que tener múltiples respuestas por pregunta es una cosa deseable en los _stacks_).@Rusla, sí, ese es el caso.